# Is there anything in the code that is unnecessary?

Tags: html, css, web

Here is an image of what I want my design to be.

[image]

1. Things to consider is that it will be a sticky footer and will always be at the bottom of the page.
2. The content page in the middle should be set to equal the distance of the header and footer and if the content is longer than the scroll bar should automatically be placed.

** IF there is anything in my code that is unnecessary please let me know. I want it to be a simple design.

**You can also notice by the JSFIDDLE that my main content div in black is really short. I removed the height because when I added content it woundn't show all of it after scrolling for a little bit. Taking out the height fixed the problem.But if I have no content on a page like the main page it is a samall rectangle on the top by the header which is not what I want. I want the content to be from the top of the header to the footer and if the content is more then it scrolls down until there is no more content?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Br7nN/)

HTML CODE:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
        <div id="header">

        </div>

        <div id="main">

</div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS CODE:

```
html, body
{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
}
#page
{
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
        height:100%;
        min-width:960px;
}
#header
{
        background-color:#115EA2;
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
}
#main
{
        width:1300px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-color:#F1F2F3;
        /*min-height:100%;
        height:auto;
        height:100%;*/
        margin:0 auto -50px;
        vertical-align:bottom;
        text-align: left;
        color:#115EA2;
        padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
}


#footer
{
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        bottom:0;
        height:35px;
        background-color: #115EA2;
}

/* NAVIGATION BAR CODE */
#navigation
{
        min-width:930px;
        position:relative;
        white-space:nowrap;
        padding:65px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: While it's a good idea to ask other people to review your code and web design, this sort of question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. This question is [primarily opinion-based](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and that's something to avoid here.

Comment: Looks like a perfect fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ however :)

Comment: What is your question? (and no, asking if we like your design is not a VALID question)

Comment: Not sure what would be unnecessary when you only have 4 divs..

Comment: @feitla My question is how to fix the the main content div? Right now if you look at it on JSFiddle it looks like a small recatangle box on the by the header. It does not span all the way down to the footer. As content is added it moves down. The issue I am having is that I want it to span between the header and footer and once content reaches the footer it will scroll down more to finish adding the content. Also my question is not about design at all that is the design in mind and I need help with my code to get it there. I think there are things that are needed to be fixed in my code.

Comment: @retailcoder Pretty much that and to see if there are certain elements I am adding in my CSS code that are not needed.

Comment: @JordanPlahn I am talking about what is unnecessary inside the css elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your fiddle with a suggestion.
If you have your footer fixed, it's better to have the header fixed too else it is going to be annoying for the user to scroll up every time he wants to navigate to another page.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Br7nN/7/)**

```
Hope this Help
```

Comment: Your example worked pretty well except for the header fixed part. When I test your example as is it works fine in chrome. When I test header:fixed; in IE the header is aligned with the main body. So the header starts like about 100px. So changing it back to relative it worked out fine.

Comment: @Krishp, you are right about IE. That is because you will need to specify the logo's dimensions. If they are larger than the available space the logo image will pull the navbar below. http://jsfiddle.net/Br7nN/8/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/Br7nN/6/

add `overflow-y:scroll;` and a `height` value like `100%` to your `#main`

I cleaned up some of the CSS that is unnecessary though there probably is more that can be removed. It's hard to say what your end goal is by just looking at some css rules.

```
    #main {
    width:1300px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
    margin:0 auto -50px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    color:black;
    padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try the code you gave me. I added the picture and description in the original question to exactly show everyone what I was trying to go for.

Comment: I tried your approach and it looks fine in JSFiddle. When I try this with my server the problem is that my header and footer are fine but when the main page is placed somewhere on the top and you can see part of the bottom of the main div on top of the header and a little passed it.